# How to run on jenkins + docker + kubernetes localy

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes, minikube

I'm trying to execute the documentation provided by [Jenkins](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/kubernetes/) to use Kubernetes + Docker + Jenkins. I'm doing that on my Ubuntu desktop and, in the end, the URL (http://192.168.49.2:32000/login) to Jenkins can't be reached (I've got "Refused to connect"). How I'm very new with docker and Kube, I don't know even how to debug that to try to discover the problem.

I'd like to know what commands could I use to debug that and solve the problem.

Comment: What URL are you trying and what error message do you get when you try to reach the Jenkins server?

Comment: http://192.168.49.2:32000/login, I just get from browser a refused o connect

Comment: When you run "kubectl get services -n jenkins" and "minikube ip", what output do you get?

Comment: From Kubectl: 
jenkins         NodePort    <IP>  <none>        8080:32000/TCP   23h 
jenkins-agent   ClusterIP   <IP>     <none>        50000/TCP        23h
and from minikube <IP>

Comment: @siamsot Running kubectl get pods -n jenkins, I've got "no resources found"

Comment: Oh, that would make sense... Please make sure that you created a service and a deployment as well.  Deployments make sure that you have pods running

Comment: @siamsot and how can I do that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230548/discussion-between-leandro-lima-and-siamsot).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have no pods running, make sure that you create a [Deployment file](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/kubernetes/#create-jenkins-deployment-file) which should be a jenkins-deployment.yaml file with these contents:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: jenkins
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: jenkins
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: jenkins
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: jenkins
        image: jenkins/jenkins:lts-jdk11
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        volumeMounts:
        - name: jenkins-home
          mountPath: /var/jenkins_home
      volumes:
      - name: jenkins-home
        emptyDir: { }
```

After that, deploy it by running the command:

```
kubectl create -f jenkins-deployment.yaml -n jenkins
```

Comment: alright, now it's deployed but, yet, I can't reach the URL.

Comment: I got pods running in jenkins namespace and list deployments there also, but, can't open URL.

Comment: It's ok now. I made a post-forward and got the jenkins admin page on localhost.

Comment: Well, I've got two more problems, firstly, I can't understand why it didn't work to install jenkins with helm; the second question is, now it doesn't acept my keys lol, even geting the secrets as in the documentation.

Comment: Have you created a persistent disk? If you don't have a persistent disk, then you won't be able to store persistent data such as the secrets. For the Helm part, I don't know exactly what you are facing so it's difficult to troubleshoot.